# I need if block to run inside try block if response generated starts with unable

Tags: python, azure, testing, botframework, large-language-model

I need if condition to work if response["answer"] contains "unable to find the answer"

try:

```
        instructions =instruction
        prompt_query = query + instructions

        response = await conv_chain.acall({"question": prompt_query, "chat_history": chat_history_new})
        
        end_time = time.time()
        logger.info("response generated in :"+str(end_time-start_time)+"secs")

        if response["answer"] == "Unable to find the relevant answer":
    
           second_instruction=instruction1
           retry_prompt_query = query + second_instruction

           response = await conv_chain.acall({"question": retry_prompt_query, "chat_history": chat_history_new})
    except:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if "unable to find the relevant answer" in response["answer"]:
```

or ignore case:

```
    if "unable to find the relevant answer".lower() in response["answer"].lower():
```